# How to use Mule object store to persist the value from first trigger to second trigger

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

I have a requirement to count the number of messages  entering in to the flow. Once it reaches 100 i need to do some process. I'm doing simple POC on this, but get struck in between the concept.

Starting of the flow, have initialize the `object store` with value `1` and incrementing the value in script `1+1= 2`, and assigning incremental value to the same `object store` as we have override option. When the second message triggered, i'm expecting  `objectstore` gives the vales as `2` so that i can increment to 3. But here the problem is, when the second message comes in, again the object store assigning the value as '1').

If i remove the override property option in first object store, it is throwing error like key already exists when the second message started triggering in to flow.

All i need to do, i need to store the incremental value when the second messages trigger.

Could any one please suggest the solution, if any code snippet would be helpful. Please find  simple my config xml

```
<objectstore:config name="ObjectStore" maxEntries="100" persistent="true" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
<flow name="OB test flow" processingStrategy="thread-per-processor">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\in" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1" value-ref="#[&quot;1&quot;]" overwrite="true" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    <enricher target="#[flowVars.initialValue]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    </enricher>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Script">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[String storePayload =  message.payload;
      String storeInitialValue= flowVars.initialValue;
    int pValue = Integer.parseInt(storeInitialValue);
    int i = 0;
     if ( i < pValue ){
     pValue=pValue+1;
   flowVars.initialValue=pValue;
  return storePayload;
   }
  ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
    <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1" value-ref="# [flowVars.initialValue]" overwrite="true" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    <enricher target="#[flowVars.finalValue]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
        <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
    </enricher>
    <logger message="***FinalValue:#[flowVars.finalValue]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="c:/out" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you always overwrite it here:

```
<objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1" value-ref="#[&quot;1&quot;]" overwrite="true" doc:name="ObjectStore"/>
```

Just try retrieving it first: then check it and overwrite it:

```
<enricher target="#[flowVars.initialValue]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <objectstore:retrieve config-ref="ObjectStore"
                key="OB1" doc:name="ObjectStore" defaultValue-ref="#[1]" />
        </enricher>

        <set-variable variableName="newValue"
            value="#[flowVars.initialValue !=null ? flowVars.initialValue + 1 : 1]"
            doc:name="Variable" />
        <objectstore:store config-ref="ObjectStore" key="OB1"
            value-ref="#[flowVars.newValue]" overwrite="true" doc:name="ObjectStore" />
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, i tried this approach. Since we  are trying to retrieve the key , and the key is not present. It is throwing error in enricher `retrieve`  "key is not present" for the first entry of message. Is there any way we can check object store key without throwing error. Please suggest and Thanks for the response.

Comment: Are we can able to supress the error  it thrown, im good to go with this approach, only blocking is error being thrown, if the key is not present.

Comment: Updated my answer. Set defaultValue-ref. If this param is not present an exception will be thrown. For reference: https://github.com/mulesoft/objectstore-connector/blob/develop/src/main/java/org/mule/modules/objectstore/ObjectStoreConnector.java#L223